# C array as a Queue increasing with X elements when full c++

Tags: c++, queue

I need to make a class for a queue. When an object of the class is created the queue should hold 5 elements at the beginning.

When the queue is full, it should increase with another 5 elements.

I have created the class, all good so far. It works perfectely, except that i don't really understand how to make the queue to be created X elements big, and to increase with x elements each time its full.

Is it possible to implement this in the class, or should it be implemented in the main code somehow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include "song.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node *next;
    Song song;
    Node(Node *n, Song song) :next(n), song(song) {}
};

// Destructor
Queue::~Queue()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

// Return true if queue is empty
bool Queue::isEmpty() const
{
    return head == 0;
}

// Add a node last in the queue
void Queue::enQue(Song song)
{
    Node *pNew = new Node(0, song);

    if (isEmpty())
        head = pNew;
    else
        tail->next = pNew;

    tail = pNew;

    nrnodes++;
}

// Remove a node first in the queue
bool Queue::deQue(Song &song)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        return false;

    Node *pDel = head;
    song = pDel->song;
    head = head->next;

    if (isEmpty())
        tail = 0;

    delete pDel;
    nrnodes--;

    return true;
}

// Clear queue
void Queue::clearQue()
{
    // Temporary node for head
    Node *pDel = head;

    // Go trhough the list node after node and delete
    while (pDel != nullptr)
    {
        // Delete head node
        head = tail->next;
        delete pDel;

        // Update head node
        pDel = head;
    }
    // Reset head and tail
    tail = head = nullptr;
}

// Print queue
void Queue::printQue() const
{
    for (Node *p = head; p; p = p->next)
    {
        cout << p->song.getTitle() << " - " << p->song.getArtist() << " " << p->song.getDuration() << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with using `std::vector` and use it's `capacity` ?

Comment: Where is the c'tor where you should be passing in X?

Comment: @Tigran I am trying to learn, and i have gone through most of whats possible with a vector as a noob. But i have never quite understood queue's and am trying to learn this thing with dynamic queues. Having queues in a queue.